# How can I verify a user doesn't exist before shoveling the user in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, duplicates, include, exists, verification

Rails newbie so bear with me...

I created a calendar app and the owner of the calendar can add other users to the calendar.  I just realized that they can add the same user many times, which obviously I don't want.  I've tried a bunch of different things including methods to check inside of the model, those didn't work... I was using includes to verify...

My current method in my controller is:

```
def update
  if @calendar.calendar_admin?(current_user)
    @new_user = User.find(params[:calendar][:user_ids])
    if @calendar.users.includes(@new_user)
      redirect_to user_calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'This user has already been added to this calendar.'
    else
      @calendar.users << @new_user
      if @calendar.save
        redirect_to user_calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Your calendar has been updated.'
      else
        redirect_to user_calendar_path(@calendar)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

No matter what, it gets stuck at "this user has already been added to this calendar", even if the user hasn't. I am shoveling the new user in but I'm not even sure if that is the right manner to add the new user?

Input?

Comment: Should it be `include?` instead of `includes`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `include?` instead of `includes`.

`include?` returns a boolean based on whether a set contains a specific item. [`includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) is a different method and will return a non-nil value that is truthy.

Comment: Ok I’ll try this too! I thought I had tried it first. I’ve tried so many things it’s hard to keep track.

Comment: I must not have tried this because it worked!! YAYYY! happy dance time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test if `@calendar.users` already contains a specific user. Unfortunately, `includes` sounds right, but it is used to add a table/model to join result (if I try to run your line it explodes).

So I suggest the following alternatives:

```
if @calendar.users.to_a.any{|uu| uu.id == @new_user.id}
```

this will fetch all users in an array and check if a user exists with the same id. This is easy to understand, but not optimal since it might retrieve a lot of data.

Probably better alternative is to use the database, and count if a user with your wanted id is linked:

```
 if @calendar.users.where("users.id" => @new_user.id).count > 0
```

Comment: So this would go in my model as a method since it’s activerecord? Or am I totally off?

Comment: Or what about a find_or_initialize_by instead of using shovel?